# icon getting bigger problem with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, query-optimization

I was using JavaScript to switch the header files when the section changes which avoids the conflict in the body. For that I am using below code:

```
function fileImporter(){
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

if (localStorage.promptmode=='0')
{
    //index for editor
    head.innerHTML=`
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Go Prompt Online</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image" href="./img/shortcut icon.jpg">
    <link rel="icon" type="image" href="./img/shortcut icon.jpg">

    <!-- start editor mode -->
    <script>starteditor();</script>
    <!-- fontawesomeIcons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sidebar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/files.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/prompt.css">
    `    
}
else
{
    //prompter
    head.innerHTML=`
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>Prompter</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6df0251b91.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/lowerslider-p.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/focusbar-p.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/prompt.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/prompter.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/speedbar.css">
`

}
var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
s.setAttribute( 'src', 'js/all.min.js' );
head.appendChild(s);
```

}

but the problem with this code is it loads the JavaScript Little slowly which gives space to icons to get as big as the whole screen
 [FULL SCREEN COVERING ICON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxbyz.png)

So is there any solution by which I can avoid this icon loading problem?
i also tried the load screen which loads after the icons get bigger which doesn't help.

Comment: one of the solutions is inline styling to the element, and btw your image is so way bigger and not even called 'icon'

Answer (score -1):

Instead of the `<link>` tag, use `<img>`. You can set a fixed height and width as well as custom styling through the `class` attribute.

```
<img src="./img/shortcut icon.jpg" alt="Shortcut Icon" width="40px" height="40px">
```

For more information, this [Geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-img-tag/) page is great!